# Dynamic selection Dimensions in multiple slicers in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Let say i have one table that table contains multiple measures and dimensions.

Requirement : In the report i have five slicers . Each slicer having same fields.
 Example(category, sub-category, city, segment, location, sales, discount,quantity) and i have one table below the slicers, when user selected  1st slicer : category it has to display category in table, 2nd slicer : sub- category it has to display in second row sub- category ,3rd : sales it has to display sales value as per category and sub category sales.

if user want two fixed measures in the table. as per this measures user will select the dimensions in the slicers

is this possible in power bi ?

please anyone help me in this problem.in my organization they use micro-strategy report this same functionality we have to replicate in power bi.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't directly possible, because this isn't the way it works in Power BI. Instead of having multiple splicers, [build an hierarchy](https://stoneridgesoftware.com/creating-hierarchies-in-power-bi/) and use one single [HierarchySlicer](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104380820?tab=Overview) for that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your rely,i really appreciated, as per hierarchy selection user can see only order which we gave.

But in my senoriO user can selection any one of the dimension which he want see in slicers that will reflect in below table as per dimension measures will show the values.

This way i achieved but large amount of volume power bi not handling,my approach is not correct way for huge data . small data can handle this approach.i need more approches to handle 1 billon data . thank you  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8TLB.png)